# Is there any way to fix the lights and shadow in this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, shadows, highlights

I had hard time figuring out what's the major problem in this editing (1st image. I manually placed the hand and sachet in this photo).

But the I figured it out after few days that it was light and shadow related problem, on especially hand.

So, to experiment, I took a real photo of a hand and sachet, with almost same angled light source (sun) and placed it on photo. It looked much much better without any special editing.

[image]

**Now the question is:** How can (if possible) I use Photoshop to fix the shadow on lights on hand in 1st picture (2nd is already fixed, but that is a *real* photo) to make it look little more realistic?

Comment: Hand looks pretty realistic to me. The easiest thing to to to alter it is to take a photo at relatively the same time of day...based on the background, I'd guess roughly around 11 am on a sunny day, The shadows and lighting *should* be relatively similar then. (the first image is merely a blown out, over-lighted, clearly indoor photo of the hand)

Comment: @Scott I think I missed something in question. Please check edit.